# display:none not working in Opera

Tags: html, css

I'm in the learning process of making my site responsive. I'm having this issue with Opera working with a specific div under @media query to "display-none". Works in all the newer browsers except Opera. Am I missing something?

CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        font-size: 75%;
    }

    #column2, #name {
        display: none;
    }

    @-o-viewport {
        width: device-width;
        height: device-height;
        max-zoom: 2;
        min-zoom: 0.5;
    }
}
```

Actual DIV I'm trying to hide in my HTML:

```
<div id="column2">
<h1 id="name">P&nbsp;U&nbsp;N&nbsp;K&nbsp;I&nbsp;E&nbsp;&nbsp;D&nbsp;E&nbsp;S&nbsp;I&nbsp;G&nbsp;N&nbsp;S</h1></div></div>
```

Viewport settings:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Comment: Since you do have Opera-specific CSS there (`-o-viewport`), does it work if you remove that? I'm not sure off the top of my head what this should do, but it's an obvious red flag.

Comment: I just added that Opera-specific tag not too long ago because I've been trying to research this. Thought that would fix it, but didn't. If I remove it, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your media query to this

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
    body {
        font-size: 75%;
    }

    #column2, #name {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It behaves in the same way on Opera Mini as on other browsers – so by using media queries and targeting the device capabilities it caters for all.

CSS3 Media Query support

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: Div still doesn't disappear when the screen reaches its specified size. What I'm trying to achieve is similar to http://charlottetang.com. Her "name, etc." disappears when the window/screen size reaches its point. Is this just a quirk Opera has? I have other settings in the @media query, works fine except this one little "display-none". Oh, and I did remove "display:block/in-line blocks" within those 2 div tags.